# SQLAlchemy - Multithreading Best Practices - Packet sequence number wrong

Tags: python, multithreading, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pymysql

I'm tring to make a clean Flask App which use SQLAlchemy and Multi-Threading.

I've read the doc : https://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/14/orm/contextual.html#thread-local-scope but can't manage to make it work successfully.

SQL Alchemy is initate directly at the app ****init**.py** file with something like that :

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app)    
session_factory = sessionmaker( bind=db.engine, autocommit=False, autoflush=False)
DBSession = scoped_session( session_factory )
```

And in another file, which **is not** some Flask routes, on a Class :

```
from blabla import DBSession
class Worker(Thread):
    def __init__(self):
        Thread.__init__(self)
        self.dbsession = DBSession()
    def run(self):
        self.dbsession.query(...)
```

When I run my app, multiple Worker Class is running at the same time.
Then I'm facing lot of errors like :

```
sqlalchemy.exc.InternalError: (pymysql.err.InternalError) Packet sequence number wrong - got 54 expected 1
```

What I am doing wrong ?

Thanks a lot in advance for your time !

Comment: Just a wild guess: are you sending objects received from sqlalchemy in one thread to be used in queries done in another thread?

Comment: I try not to ! I use `sqlalchemy.orm.object_session(my_object)` everytime I have a doubt. I'll check again.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like maybe you are duplicating the scoped session already provided by flask sqlalchemy.  You can probably use db.session directly.  Although you have to clean it up yourself when the thread ends or at regular intervals with `db.session.remove()` because it isn't within a request like flask expects.  Why are you adding custom threading ?

https://flask-sqlalchemy.palletsprojects.com/en/2.x/quickstart/#road-to-enlightenment

> a preconfigured scoped session called session

Comment: Thanks about your answer ! I've used this way previously but facing too often two types of errors : 1- "out of context" error. It help to add "with app.app_context() :" but It can be hard to apply that everywhere. 2- "QueuePool limit of size X overflow Y reached" a tremondous amount of sessions wich makes me play with SQLALCHEMY_POOL_SIZE and SQLALCHEMY_MAX_OVERFLOW. But, again, don't feel to be the best way of doing it.

Comment: Yeah I don't think there are many advantages of having tons of custom threads outside of a request especially within Python and additionally while also running a flask app in the same process.  What are you trying to accomplish with all those custom threads?

Comment: My app is a classic Web API with routes and requests. But, meanwhile another thread is running and looking for new tasks in database. When a new task is find, a worker is launch. Many workers had to be running at the same time, each worker executing multiple database query.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to comments and answer, I've made it worky pretty smoothly. Just need to thinks it from scratch.

On my app.py :

```
db = SQLAlchemy(app, session_options={"autocommit":False, "autoflush":False, "expire_on_commit":False })
```

Ian highlighted that the Object db.session is already a scoped session. So no need to create another one manually.
Moreover, I didn't know that it's possible to add session_options directly at this step. Obviously it's easier to directly configure the already integrated one.

On my others files :

```
dbsession = db.session
dbsession.query(...)
...
dbsession.commit()
dbsession.close()
```

Each new db.session seems to create a "real" session, I can see them directly on my MySQL instance. So, It's very important to close() and limit the number of concurent threads.

Did you see something wrong in this way ? The answer is **YES**.

---

**EDIT :** With Flask-SQLALchemy V3 comes a new way of deals whith context. The session scope to use the current app context instead of the thread. That is a problem when used out of context.

It's possible to add `with app.app_context():` at some points. But it's not clear for me where it has to be done. And I feel like this will overload my code.

Maybe it's possible to come back to the previous behaviour directly from the params ? Don't know how to for the moment.

Comment: Nope. Facing `Working outside of application context` errors on my production environment.  Maybe versions differs. I'll check that.

Comment: Yep, begginers mistake. Flask-SQLAlchemy v2.5.1 in my dev environment and v3.0.2 in production environment. I've upgrade and the out of context error appear immediatly.

Comment: Seems to be link to that point in the release note : `The session is scoped to the current app context instead of the thread. This requires that an app context is active. This ensures that the session is cleaned up after every request.`